# How to use kubectl debug to check the running processes of an existing contianer in a pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to see details `ps aux` of one particular process in a container. I have a deployment with one container in it. The deployment has

```yaml
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsNonRoot: true
```

In order to see the processes running in the container I tried to launch a temporary new container in the same space as the existing one. This new container should have access to same processes and resources (this is what I believe and wanted to test). The command I use is

```shell
kubectl debug pod-name -c my-new-container --image=busybox -it -- sh
```

When I ran it I got a warning,
**"container busybox: container has runAsNonRoot and image will run as root"**

After this message prompt does not return. It hangs.

Is it because of the **runAsNonRoot**? If it is what is the workaround?